# Modifying file extensions using Makefiles

Tags: makefile

I'm new to Makefiles and I want to modify the extension of a set of files. The following command works on the shell:

```
for file in path/*.ext1; do j=`echo $file | cut -d . -f 1`;j=$j".ext2";echo mv $file $j; done
```

However, I'm not sure how to run this in a Makefile. I tried running

```
$(shell for file in path/*.ext1; do j=`echo $file | cut -d . -f 1`;j=$j".ext2";echo mv $file $j; done)
```

But this never did what I needed it to do. What do I need to do to make this work on the Makefile? How do I call it in a section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is that the `$` character is special to make: it introduces a make variable.  If you want to pass a `$` to the shell, you'll have to write two of them: `$$`.

So, your `shell` function invocation would have to be written as:

```
$(shell for file in path/*.ext1; do j=`echo $$file | cut -d . -f 1`;j=$$j".ext2";echo mv $$file $$j; done)
```

However, this is almost certainly not a good way to do what you want.  You don't really describe clearly what you want to do, however.  If you just want to have a target in a makefile that can be invoked to make this change, you can use:

```
fixext:
        for file in path/*.ext1; do \
            j=`echo $$file | cut -d . -f 1`; \
            j=$$j".ext2"; \
            echo mv $$file $$j; \
        done
```

Or, taking advantage of some useful shell shortcuts, you could just run:

```
fixext:
        for file in path/*.ext1; do \
            echo mv $$file $${file%.*}.ext2; \
        done
```

Now if you run `make fixext` it will perform those steps.

But, a much more make-like way to do it would be to write a single rule that knows how to rename one file, then use prerequisites to have them all renamed:

```
TARGETS = $(patsubst %.ext1,%.ext2,$(wildcard path/*.ext1))

fixext: $(TARGETS)

%.ext2 : %.ext1
        mv $< $@
```

Now you can even run `make -j5` and do 5 of the move commands in parallel...

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestions worked perfectly. The reason why I needed to do is this because I needed to convert .c to .cpp files since I was getting files that were .c instead of .cpp from another tool.

Comment: Hm.  this is a good example of a time when you should specify exactly what you want to do rather than abstracting it to some generic "ext".  Renaming a `.c` file (which is written in the C programming language) to a `.cpp` file (which is presumed to be written in the C++ programming language) is _not_ a good idea.  Although C++ is "sort-of" a superset of C, there are many areas in which they're not compatible and trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler can definitely lead to issues.  Why do you want to do this, instead of just compiling your C code as C code with a C compiler?

Comment: Also, creating a rule like `%.cpp : %.c` which renames the file can be dangerous: if you create a new `foo.c` afterward and rerun `make` it will rename `foo.c` to `foo.cpp` overwriting `foo.cpp` and any changes to it you might have made...

Comment: Yes you are right. It is dangerous to convert .c to .cpp. However, I'm working with code generation and my dependency are on files that are generated by another tool called Ptolemy (http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/) and I know for sure that the files that were named .c were ok to be .cpp. I'm not yet in a position to change the source code for that project and so I was looking at this work around for the time being.

Comment: Also, the code generation is for mbed and there have been a few issues that I've been facing with building .c files with arm-none-eabi-gcc. They need arm-none-eabi-g++. Here is the link to the mbed error that I was getting: https://developer.mbed.org/forum/mbed/topic/5205/?page=1#comment-27447. The only difference is that I'm facing this issue on the Mac OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

you can also add rename blocks at the top of your file eg to change a suffix

```
output := $(input:.mov=.mp4)
```

but this won't work inside a make command as far as I can see

```
check:
    output := $(input:.mov=.mp4)
```

gives

```
$ input=walkthrough.mov make check
output := walkthrough.mp4
make: output: No such file or directory
make: *** [check] Error 1
```